# Rotating a div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am sorry that title is not really specific what I want to achieve using JavaScript.

I want to create a effect in which a div (Black Rectangle) is rotating on X axis and going
downwards. Its like by flipping its moving downwards.

And please no jQuery!

Any kind of hint would be appreciated.

Image of effect I want to achieve:

[image]

```js
//don't know what to do in flip function
function flip(a,b) {
    var d=document.getElementById('box');
    d.style.transform="rotateX("+a+"deg)";
    d.style.transformOrigin=b;
    //alert(b);
}

setTimeout(function() {
    flip(180, "bottom");
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function() {
    flip(180, "top");
}, 2000);
```

```css
.box {
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    transition-property:all;
    transition-duration:1s;
    
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#555;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="box"> </div>
```

Comment: Learn how setTimeout works, you're not referencing the function, but calling it right away, so your timeouts don't work at all.

Comment: Start here: http://jsfiddle.net/fjtz73vs/

Comment: @adeno: setTimeout is working.

Comment: @ArunSharma it can't possibly be.

Comment: Oh,sorry i was wrong. Only one line of setTimeout was working.
Correct way is to reference the flip function. got it.

Comment: Have you seen this solution: http://www.ajaxblender.com/howto-rotate-image-using-javascript-canvas.html